# How to create shared dataset (tabular model) in power BI report server?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

On a new report I have selected sql datasoucre, couple of tables setup relationships. This dataset model is now published to power bi report server and scheduled to refresh every hour. This results in an behind the scene SSAS model on the power bi report server.

How can I reuse the above dataset model in one or more new power BI report server report?

I know odata can be used to fetch the report's dataset. But I want to share the model with multiple reports (live connection) like how we do in Power BI service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it in Power BI Desktop for Report Server like you can with the Power BI Service. It is a [requested feature](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=4874dca0-b00b-4e08-8567-be190b99a17b), but not on the roadmap at this time

Comment: Is creating the model in SSAS and then reusing in multiple reports an option?

Comment: That would be the recommended approach